# Define a surjective ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x]\rightarrow R$ or explain why none exists

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In each case define a surjective ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x]\rightarrow R$ or explain why none exists

a) $R = \mathbb{F}_2$, the field with $2$ elements

b) $R = \mathbb{F}_4$, the field with $4$ elements

c) $R = \mathbb{Q}$

My attempt: I think my understanding of the question may be a bit naive. For a) I was imagining a function that sends polynomials with even constant term to $0$ and polynomials with odd constant term to $1$, which I think is alright as a ring homomorphism.

For b) I'm not sure, as the operations in $\mathbb{F}_4$ seem a bit more complicated than for $\mathbb{F}_3$.

Intuitively, I think c) is false, but I'm not sure how to explicitly show this. I was imagining some contradiction from mapping $z\rightarrow\frac{p}{q}$ meaning we must map $qz\rightarrow p$

Any help appreciated!

Comment: hint: z(x) has only one generator since the map is surjective $R$ must have one generator

Comment: I think you can just check the cardinalities right?

Comment: @Nameless NO! In all of these cases, $\Bbb Z[x]$ has at least as many elements as $R$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, you gotta educate me. I thought the first one for example has 2 elements right? I'll excuse myself on $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @Nameless right. We're asking about **surjective** (not injective) maps from a big set to a smaller set.

Comment: Sorry my suggestion meant to *eliminate* choices, I didn't really read the question carefully.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Your map for (a) works perfectly well!  Here's another perspective on this map you've made: given a polynomial $p(x) \in \Bbb Z[x]$, we can define a homomorphism from $\Bbb Z[x]$ to $\Bbb F_2[x]$ in which we replace all coefficients with their equivalence class modulo $2$ (that is, using the quotient map from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z_2$).  Then, we found a surjective homomorphism from $\Bbb F_2[x]$ to $\Bbb F_2$.

Instead of getting a surjective homomorphism from $\Bbb F_2[x]$ to $\Bbb F_2$, look for a surjective homomorphism from $\Bbb F_2[x]$ to $\Bbb F_4$.  You'll need to look at how $\Bbb F_4$ is defined.

For (c), you have the right idea.  Note that once we know what $\phi$ does to the polynomial $x$, we know everything about the homomorphism $\phi:\Bbb Z[x] \to \Bbb Q$.  Conclude that no matter what we choose $\phi(x)$ to be, we will always be missing at least some denominator.